# Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

When creating a virtual environment with no -site packages do I need to install mysql & the mysqldb adapter which is in my global site packages in order to use them in my virtual project environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also (on UNIX) symlink specific packages from the Python site-packages into your virtualenv's site-packages.

Comment: +1, I was trying to capture the symlinks from my virtual env so that I could put it here. When, I came back you had already answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you will need to install then exclusively for this virtualenv.

See: http://virtualenv.openplans.org/#the-no-site-packages-option

If you build with virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV it will not inherit any packages from global site package directory.

If you see the files inside the site-packages directory, the packages are made via symlinks.

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 ashish  staff    102 Nov 24 20:52 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 ashish  staff     85 Nov 24 20:52 UserDict.py -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py
.....
```

So you could definitely add packages manually by creating these symlinks for specific package.

Adam Vandenberg correctly answers that.

Comment: Hey thank you for your help & answer. I can also use pip & or easy_install to install the packages I want also correct?

Comment: @demet8: Thanks a lot.  I was a bit late in providing the complete answer. Please accept Adam Vandenberg's answer as he beat me to it.

Comment: @Adam Vandenberg: @demet8: Thanks for making the change. It was important.